# Zend_Layout for modules

Tags: zend-framework

How can I make every module have it's own layouts directory?

I.e. when I don't have any modules my layout entry in config file looks like this:

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
```

I try entering i.e.

```
; Layout directory for admin module
admin.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/layouts"
```

Where admin is module name; but it doesn't work. For some strange reason ZF looks for module layouts in /module/admin/views/scripts directory.

I also have a separate module.ini config file for every module as per [this tutorial](http://blog.vandenbos.org/2009/07/07/zend-framework-module-config/), alas layout path there gets ignored as well. Also I've been trying to follow this modules [layout tutorial](http://blog.vandenbos.org/2009/07/19/zend-framework-module-specific-layout/) but it didn't work, I guess due to differences in ZF versions (tutorial is rather old). So I don't know what else to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plugin from the tutorial you are talked about:

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_RequestedModuleLayoutLoader extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $config     = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getOptions();
        $moduleName = $request->getModuleName();

        if (isset($config[$moduleName]['resources']['layout'])) {
            Zend_Layout::startMvc($config[$moduleName]['resources']['layout']);
        }
    }
}
```

application.ini

```
resources.frontController.plugins.layoutloader = My_Controller_Plugin_RequestedModuleLayoutLoader
```

module.ini:

```
resources.layout.layout = "Admin"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/layouts/scripts"
```

Working fine.

Comment: Updated answer with application.ini settings

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally got it working, after lots of tweaking in my application.ini

Answer (score 2):

A slightly alternate method to Ololo recommendation (which is a great way to do it)..

```
class YourApp_Controller_Plugin_Modulelayout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
     public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
     {
          $module = $request->getModuleName();
          if ($module != 'default')
          {
              if (file_exists(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/' . $module . '.html')) {
                  Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout($module);
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Place this controller plugin in /library/YourApp/Controller/Plugin/Modulelayout.php
Then save your module layouts as the module name in your layouts folder (E.g., /layout/admin.phtml). If it does not find a layout for that module, it will default back to layout.phtml or whatever you originally set it to.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer having module layouts in module directories, i.e. having modules as independent as possible. But this is a great way too, I may need it in some future projects.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this gist - https://gist.github.com/891384

This uses a combination of

- Action helper to inspect the requested module and given a matching configuration, change the layout's `layout` and `layoutPath` properties in the `preDispatch` hook
- Application resource plugin to capture module layout options, inject them into the above helper and add it to the helper broker

Answer (score 1):

Happened  to me too I got around it by using this line in my controller (I created a init function)

```
Zend_Layout::startMvc(array('layoutPath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/layouts'));
```

Comment: Well thank you but in such case it's better to store layouts in their default location than to add config code to every single controller I have. Though I still hope there's a real solution

Answer (score 0):

As of Zend Framework 1.12 (Haven't tested it on previous releases):

1. Create your modules
2. Initialize the layout in your prefered fashion. For example in application.ini as zend tools does it:

   ```
   resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
   ```
3. Create a layout inside each module with the default layout name inside the modules path to "views/scripts/" for example "application/modules/default/views/scripts/layout.phtml"

Don't forget to create one for the default module as it will be your fallback layout!

**DO NOT create the default layout inside /application/layouts/scripts or this won't work**

You are ready to run!

When Zend_Layout doesn't find the default layut it will look into the modules folders for it.

If you need some extra tweaking you may create a plugin and assign it to the layout object itself. For example, inside application.ini:

```
resources.layout.pluginClass = "MyLibrary_Controller_Plugin_Layout"
```

...or in the Bootstrap:

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setPluginClass("MyLibrary_Controller_Plugin_Layout");
```

Cheers!